# What happens when an intermediate hop router encounters a packet whose MTU size is more than what it can handle?

Tags: router, ip, mtu, packet-loss

Basically if the frame size of a packet is more than the MTU size configured in the router (which is an intermediate hop) the packet is dropped. Since IP does not have any ARQ mechanism, is there a method to know at source that packets are being dropped? What is the thing to do in this scenario. Does the network operator ensure manually this does not happen?

Comment: Besides Ron's answer, look up PMTUD. Fragmentation is built into IPv4, but IPv6 has eliminated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the MTU of the outgoing interface is smaller than the packet, the router will fragment the packet *unless* the DF flag is set. In that case the router will drop the packet and send an ICMP packet too big message back to the sender.